# Child to get 100% of parent that's flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I've got the following setup

```html
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
     Some content
    </div>
</div>
```

And for CSS

```css
.a{
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.b{
  height: 100%;
}
```

I’m trying to make the inner *div* be 100% the height of the parent whose height is determined using `flex-grow`, but my current code doesn’t seem to work. Is it possible to achieve given that the parent's size is determined using Flexbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the `a` a flex conainer and the `b` will by default stretch to fill 100% of the height:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.a {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.b {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="b">
      Some content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can write this code

```
<div class="a">
<div class="b">
 Some content
</div>
<div class="b">
 Some content
</div>
<div class="b">
 Some content
</div>
```

Comment: .a{
   overflow: auto;
    background-color: skyblue;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    height: 400px;
}

.b{
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}